# Node js Rest Service save data into specific object json

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

I'm developing a REST API with Node JS.
I have developed post request but don't try to save data on a specific object of MongoDB Schema.
I have this MongoDB schema

```
var ProfileSchema = db.Schema({
farmId: { type: String, required: true },
companyName: { type: String, required: true },
firstname: {type: String, required: true},
surname: {type: String, required: true},
address: {type: String, required: true},
city: {type: String, required: true},
state: {type: String, required: false},
postalcode: {type: String, required: true},
country: {type: String, required: true},
telephone: {type: String, required: true},
email: {type: String, required: true},
demographics:{
farmSize: {type: String, required: true },
crops: {type: String, required: true},
liveStock: {type: String, required: true},
precisionFarming: {type: String, required: true},
currentTire: {type: String, required: false}
}
});
```

and this my post request:

```
router.post('/profile', VerifyToken, function (req, res) {
Profile.create({
    farmId:req.body.farmId,
    companyName:req.body.companyName,
    firstname:req.body.firstname,
    surname: req.body.surname,
    address: req.body.address,
    city: req.body.city,
    state: req.body.state,
    postalcode: req.body.postalcode,
    country: req.body.country,
    telephone: req.body.telephone,
    email: req.body.email,
    farmSize: req.body.farmSize,
    crops: req.body.crops,
    liveStock: req.body.liveStock,
    precisionFarming: req.body.precisionFarming,
    currentTire: req.body.currentTire
    },
    function (err, profile) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
        res.status(200).send({status: 'ok', data: { msg: 'Profile saved'}});

    });
  });
```

How can i save the data into "demographics" object?
My code give erro 500.
Any help please, is very importat for me to fix this problem.

Best

This error log:

```
{ ValidationError: ProfileFarm validation failed:    demographics.precisionFarming: Path `demographics.precisionFarming` is     required., demographics.liveStock: Path `demographics.liveS
tock` is required., demographics.crops: Path `demographics.crops` is required., demographics.farmSize: Path `demographics.farmSize` is required.
```

Comment: Can you post the **err**?? 

    function (err, profile) {
        if (err) {**console.log(err);**
return res.status(500).send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");}
        res.status(200).send({status: 'ok', data: { msg: 'Profile saved'}});

    });

Comment: I have added the error code into my post

Comment: Can you log your `req.body`?
Your model definition has few fields marked as **required** and I am afraid you are not passing to them or they are going undefined, eg: crop, liveStock, etc

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for your help i have solved usig thib in my req.body 'demographics.farmSize': req.body.farmSize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you log your `req.body`?

Your schema definition has few fields marked as required and I am afraid you are not passing to them or they are going undefined, eg: crop, liveStock, etc
Here's what you can do:

- Send all the data properly

Or

- just change the schema definition and remove the required flags, or set them to false it would start working.